# Forced image reload after upload shows previously uploaded image

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

I have the following markup:

The user can select a photo resource which will be uploaded to the server and displayed as a background image of a div container on top of the form.

```
<div id="self" style="background-image: url(self.jpg)"></div>

<form id="photo_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/photo" method="post">

    <input type="file" id="select_photo" name="photo" />

</form>
```

I want the background image to be reloaded as soon as a new image has been uploaded. I add a timestamp to the image URL to force a reload.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function reloadBackground(tag) {
        // get background image source
        var source = tag.css('background-image').slice(4, -1);

        var index = source.lastIndexOf('?');

        if (index > -1) {
            // remove time stamp
            source = source.substring(0, index);
        }

        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function() {
            // set new background image source
            tag.css('background-image', 'url(' + image.src + ')');
        }

        // add time stamp to force reload
        image.src = source + '?t=' + (new Date().getTime());
    }

    $('#select_photo').change(function() {
        $('#photo_upload').ajaxSubmit({
            error: function(response) {
                console.error(response.status);
            },

            success: function(response) {
                reloadBackground($('#self'));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Here's the problem:

The first time I select and upload a new image, the background image does not change. After I select another photo, the background image changes to show the photo which was uploaded before, etc. However, if I reload the page manually, the correct (i.e. the last uploaded) image is displayed. It seems that reloadBackground() is called too early.

Do you have an idea what is going wrong?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

For the sake of completeness, this is how the image is served by nodeJS:

```
app.get('/self.jpg', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(user.id + '.jpg', {
        root: uploadDir
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(error.status).end();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh. I found the problem:

After an image has been uploaded, I use the lwip library to scale the image and save it to its destination path. This can take up to two seconds but the success callback of ajaxSubmit() is, of course, called as soon as the image has been uploaded.

So I guess I can either keep a copy of the image in the upload folder under its original name or I find a way to tell the client to reload the image as soon as the image has been processed and written to its destination path.

Answer (score 0):

```
function reloadBackground(tag) {
    // get background image source
    var source = tag.css('background-image').slice(4, -1);

    var index = source.lastIndexOf('?');

    if (index > -1) {
        // remove time stamp
        source = source.substring(0, index);
    }

    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function() {
        // set new background image source
        tag.css('background-image', 'url(' + image.src + ')');
    }

    // add time stamp to force reload
    image.src = source + '?t=' + (new Date().getTime());
}
```

put this part out of the `document` ready function

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but this does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return only the file name from server and use an img tag to display it:

```
<div id="self">
    <img src="self.jpg" alt="Self"/>
</div>

<form id="photo_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/photo" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="select_photo" name="photo"/>
</form>
```

and the js:

```
function reloadBackground(source) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        $('#self img').replaceWith(image);
    };

    image.src = source;
}

$('#select_photo').change(function() {
    $('#photo_upload').ajaxSubmit({
        error: function(response) {
            console.error(response.status);
        },

        success: function(response) {
            // Verify how to get image file name (Should be in the response)
            var source = response.data;
            reloadBackground(source);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: If I do not add a timestamp, like you suggest, the image is not reloaded at all. If I keep the timestamp but use an image tag which is replaced by the new image, it's the same problem as before, i.e. the displayed image is always the previously uploaded one.

Thanks anyway!